# How to post a multipart/form-data using browsers formdata via a test

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data, form-data

I have have built a javascript sdk. The following function works nicely in the browser.

```
async submitDocument(id, side, image) {

    const url = this.API_URL + "/document";

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", image, "front.jpg");
    formData.append("side", side);

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.API_KEY);

    const request = {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
        headers: headers,
    };

    try {

        const response = await fetch(url, request);
        const data = await response.json();

        return data;

    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }

}
```

I want to create a test for this function using jest library.

```
test("should submit front document", async () => {

    const side = "front";
    const fsp = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
    const f = await fsp(process.cwd() + "/test/resources/" + "id/front.jpg");
    const imageFile = new File([f], "front.jpeg", { type: "image/jpg", lastModified: new Date() });

    const front = await mysdk.submitDocument(id, side, imageFile);
    expect(front.success).toBe(true);
});
```

formdata requires the file input to be of type blob https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData, as you can see ive attempting to convert to a blob/file.

However when this gets submitted i can see in the node.js backend the headers content-type and content-length are empty.

```
{
  authorization: 'Bearer <REMOVED>',
  referer: 'http://localhost/',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (darwin) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) jsdom/11.12.0',
  'accept-language': 'en',
  accept: '*/*',
  origin: 'http://localhost',
  host: 'localhost:3002',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'content-length': '0',
  connection: 'close'
}
```

Comment: I think the issue is that formdata sets the content-type in the browser automatically, now because my jest test is not running via a browser it does not know how to set the content-type multipart/form-data but more specifically the boundary between the parts